# ViewPager with varying off screen page code

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Say I have a ViewPager with 7 "pages" and I'm viewing page number 4:

> 1 2 3 [4] 5 6 7

With the following setting,

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

the ViewPager is going to load (or call getItem() function from FragmentStatePagerAdapter) all 7 pages.

Is there a way I can call a separate function/code for the page that is currently being displayed (page 4 in this case)? For example, I'm trying to have gallery of images, and I want to load low-quality images on pages 1,2,3,5,6,and 7 while loading high-quality image for page 4 for optimal memory management. When a user switches to page 5, all other pages except 5 should have low-quality image. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would create your own ViewPager and implement the callback function  `setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener)`  then, you can catch a trigger on `ViewPager.SETTLING` to update the current view with a higher resolution image.  By catching it on `ViewPager.SETTLING` you can start to load that higher resolution image before it even finishes settling on `ViewPager.IDLING`.